# Custom field editor for NSTextFieldCell in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstableview, fieldeditor

I have a custom `NSTableView` subclass filled with several custom `NSTextFieldCell` subclasses. I would like to be able to change the edited cell by using the arrow keys.

I am able to accomplish this by creating a custom field editor (by subclassing `NSTextView`) and returning it from the window delegate like so:

```
- (id) windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *) aWindow toObject:(id) anObject {
    if ([anObject isEqual:myCustomTable]) {
        if (!myCustomFieldEditor) {
            myCustomFieldEditor = [[MyNSTextViewSubclass alloc] init];
            [myCustomFieldEditor setTable:anObject];
        }
        return myCustomFieldEditor;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

In `MyNSTextViewSubclass`, I override the `moveUp:`, `moveDown:`, `moveLeft:`, and `moveRight:` methods to implement my desired functionality, and that all works fine. The only problem is that the field editor no longer behaves like a text field cell editor. For example, when I hit the Enter key, it inserts a newline into the text field instead of ending the editing.

**How do I create a custom field editor that responds exactly like the default one does for an `NSTextFieldCell` (except for those four functions that I will override)?** Or is there a better way to change the functionality of`moveUp:`, `moveDown:`, `moveLeft:`, and `moveRight:`?

**EDIT:** It appears that the field editor sets the text field as its delegate when it is selected for editing. In that case, it might be helpful to just attach to the `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` delegate method as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001815-131200), but when I implement that function in either my `NSTextFieldCell` subclass or my `NSTableView` subclass, it never gets called. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent almost all day on this problem, but I finally figured it out. In order to be able to traverse my NSTableView subclass with the arrow keys, I had to add the following method to my NSTableView:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if(aSelector == @selector(moveUp:)) {
        [self moveSelectionToPreviousRow];
        return YES;
    } else if(aSelector == @selector(moveDown:)) {
        [self moveSelectionToNextRow];
        return YES;
    } else if(aSelector == @selector(moveLeft:)) {
        [self moveSelectionToPreviousColumn];
        return YES;
    } else if(aSelector == @selector(moveRight:)) {
        [self moveSelectionToNextColumn];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This is because the default field editor is an NSTextView (not an NSControl) so I needed to use the `<NSTextViewDelegate>` protocol. The view that is set as its delegate is the NSTableView, **not** the NSTextFieldCell. The `moveSelectionTo...` functions are custom functions defined in my NSTableView subclass that keep track of the currently edited cell and then move it around accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[Possibly related entry in Apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

### setFieldEditor:

Controls whether the text views sharing the receiver’s layout manager behave as field editors.

```
- (void)setFieldEditor:(BOOL)flag
```

#### Parameters

*flag*: `YES` to cause the text views sharing the receiver's layout manager to behave as field editors, `NO` otherwise.

#### Discussion

Field editors interpret Tab, Shift-Tab, and Return (Enter) as cues to end editing and possibly to change the first responder. Non-field editors instead accept these characters as text input. See “Text Fields, Text Views, and the Field Editor” for more information on field editors. By default, text views don’t behave as field editors.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you need is to implement `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` in the table view's delegate.

See also my answer to a similar question here: [Arrow keys with NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612805/arrow-keys-with-nstableview/2684173#2684173)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the more general title of this question can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865953/43615

Basically, one subclasses `NSTextFieldCell` and overrides `fieldEditorForView:`, where one simply creates a custom subclass of `NSTextView` and sets its `fieldEditor` property to `YES`.

Answer (score -1):

These should be overridden in `keyDown:(NSEvent *)event` method of your subclassed `NSTextFieldCell` object. You check the pressed key (one of the arrows) and otherwise call up to `super`.

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, but it doesn't look like the NSTextFieldCell inherits from NSResponder. When I implement that function, the compiler gives me the warning "'NSTextFieldCell' may not respond to '-keyDown:'" and the function is never called.

I even tried overriding -keyDown: in the NSTableView subclass, but it only kicks in when there is no cell currently selected for editing.